# Setting root password in fresh mysql 5.7 installation

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am trying to install mysql in a serving having `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511`. Take a look to the process installation:

```
# sudo yum install mysql-server
```

Output:

```
Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                 Arch                                    Version                                         Repository                                           Size
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 mysql-community-client                                  x86_64                                  5.7.10-1.el7                                    @mysql57-community                                  109 M
 mysql-community-server                                  x86_64                                  5.7.10-1.el7                                    @mysql57-community                                  652 M

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

I ran the mysql damon:

```
# sudo service mysqld start
```

Checking the service:

```
# ps -ef|grep mysql
mysql     1371     1  0 22:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Here comes the problem driving me crazy. I want to set root password for the very first time, so I did:

```
# sudo mysql_secure_installation
// when password is required, I just type "enter key"
```

But the output: Securing the MySQL server deployment.

> Enter password for user root:  Error: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Googling the error, in 90% of cases, the solution is to call `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` command:

```
service mysqld stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql --user=root mysql
update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

But `mysqld_safe` prompts an "command not found" error. I also tested with `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`, but it does not do anything. I will appreciate if you guide me to the right direction in order to set root password. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need those binaries to be in the `PATH`.  Or you need full paths.  (This is more of a Linux question than a MySQL question.)

Comment: [Mysql 5.7.24 get root first login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236470/2153910)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my insane research for a solution I took a look to `/var/log/mysqld.log` and found this line:

> [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: abc123

Looks like mysql 5.7+ generates a random password in the installation and prompted in that file.

Answer (score 23):

If you just run mysql command under root user you will be granted access without asked for password, because socket authentication enabled for root@localhost.

This guide is misleading.

The only way to set password is to switch to native authentication like:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

Comment: You are the savior! Work as charm!.

Comment: That's not true. # sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 8):

Use the below steps to reset the password:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Reset the MySQL server root password.

```
$sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Output something like:

```
10.744785Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: o!5y,oJGALQa
```

Use the above password during reset *mysql_secure_installation* process.

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

You have successfully reset the root password of MySQL server. Use the below command to check the MySQL server connecting or not.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

See my article: [Install Latest MySQL 5.7 on RHEL/Centos 7](http://gotechnies.com/install-latest-mysql-5-7-rhelcentos-7/)

Answer (score 4):

All of the above did not work for me and note, I spent an hour or more trying all other suggestions from MYSql website to everything on SO, I finally got it working with:

**Note:** while it showed Enter password for user root, I didnt have the original password so I just entered the same password to be used as the new password.

**Note:** there was no /var/log/mysqld.log only /var/log/mysql/error.log

1. kill the current mysqld pid
2. run mysqld with sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld &
3. run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

   **Output from mysql_secure_installation**

   > root@myServer:~# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
   >
   > Securing the MySQL server deployment.
   >
   > Enter password for user root:
   >
   > VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
   >   and improve security. It checks the strength of password
   >   and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
   >   secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?
   >
   > Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: no
   >   Using existing password for root.
   >   Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > New password:
   >
   > Re-enter new password:
   >   By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
   >   allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
   >   a user account created for them. This is intended only for
   >   testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
   >   You should remove them before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from
   >   'localhost'. This ensures that someone cannot guess at
   >   the root password from the network.
   >
   > Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that
   >   anyone can access. This is also intended only for testing,
   >   and should be removed before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > - Dropping test database...
   >     Success.
   > - Removing privileges on test database...
   >     Success.
   >
   > Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes
   >   made so far will take effect immediately.
   >
   > Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > All done!